# how to handle to click on dynamic link on the webpage which I have keyed in

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have entered a value in a text field which becomes a link later point of time when i filled in rest of the details on the webpage and i have to click on it now. The hyperlink is changing everytime with the input. How do i make selenium to click on the hyperlink without hard coding it.

xml for the text field:

```
<table id="s_2_l" tabindex="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-labelledby="" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" style="width: 5087px;" summary="Contacts" datatable="1" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Xml for the value which changes to hyperlink:

```
<a role="textbox" href="javascript:void(0);" class="drilldown" name="Last Name" tabindex="-1">HOMEOWNER</a>
```

Comment: xml for the text field:
<table id="s_2_l" tabindex="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-labelledby="" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" style="width: 5087px;" summary="Contacts" datatable="1" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

Xml for the value which changes to hyperlink:
<a role="textbox" href="javascript:void(0);" class="drilldown" name="Last Name" tabindex="-1">HOMEOWNER</a>

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in java:

```
String textfield ="HOMEOWNER";// to store text in variable
driver.findElement(By.id("s_2_l")).sendKeys(textfield); // to enter text
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='"+textfield+"'")).click();// to click on hyperlink
```